# Easy install of PHP/MySQL/NGINX server on Linux

Tags: linux, php, mysql, nginx

So I want to get my own server running but before I spend the money for one I want to make sure I can get the stuff I need installed.

Is there any packages for linux like there are for windows to easily install PHP/MySQL/NGINX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Ubuntu Server, there's a script I use all the time when setting up web servers, it's the [VladGh.com-LEMP](https://github.com/vladgh/VladGh.com-LEMP) on GitHub, the author is pretty good at keeping it up-to-date.

It installs the latest version of MySQL the Ubuntu servers have and builds the latest version of PHP and Nginx.

If you don't know much about Nginx the [Nginx Wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org) is a great place to get to know it better.

Comment: So I pretty much just run the install.sh file and it does it all for me? I'll give this a shot and see how it goes. And thanks for the link to the wiki, going to read the config docs while it runs the install. Will accept if it works for me.

Comment: Hey hey hey! works like a charm! thanks again, for this and the other question!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)